# How do I change Unity launcher theme color?

Tags: 14.04, themes, tweak

I wanna change Unity launcher theme color in Ubuntu 14.04LTS, so I read [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/how-to-easily-skin-ubuntus-unity-desktop/) article. It says to use MyUnitiy but I cant find it in Software Center. Which repository should I add to install MyUnity?

Comment: I think that tool is not for ubuntu 14.04

Comment: don't have any suggestion ? :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This tells you why you can't install it: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/myunity

What do you say about Unity Tweak Tool?

[image]

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Unity Tweak Tool, Gnome Tweak Tool, CCSM, Gnome Colors and changing themes; but I can't set the launcher to be transparent!

[As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3yMa.jpg), if I set the launcher to be any color, it works perfectly for the topbar, but not for the launcher. [When I set "based on wallpaper"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYK74.jpg), again works for the topbar, but the launcher turns in that dark grey.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

I have tried all, I know it's not crucial, but I'm pissed off now!. I have been even looking at the .css files of ambiance, trying to find a block about the launcher and tweak it manually, but I couldn't do it. (I'm a CSS illiterate though)