# How to change the system color from orange in 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, system

Can I change the "orange" of Ubuntu?

For example, I want to change:

- the folders;
- the button highlights when you hover over them;
- the buttons too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the "highlight color situation goes, the simple way seems to be to install dconf-editor (which I use, just not for changing colors, normally)

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Then just search dconf-tools in the launcher

Source: [How do I change the "Selected Items" color?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63126/how-do-i-change-the-selected-items-color)

If you want to change the background of the launcher itself, it looks as though you're headed into some more in-depth territory, but this:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/02/how-to-change-unity-2d-launcher-colour-and-opacity

shows you how to do it with just a few terminal commands and two lines of code, plus some hacking of your own to figure out which color you like. Personally, I'd use HTML color codes, because you can look up some nice tables like this one:

http://html-color-codes.info

and just sort of go with what you like.

Answer (score 0):

There is also very nice tool called [myUnity](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/myunity) which allows you to modify a lot of color settings. It has already been outlined in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460158/how-do-i-change-unity-launcher-theme-color).