# How do I install the Human theme on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, themes

I have a package named `human-theme_0.39.2_all.deb`. I want to install it and use it on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. How do I do that?

Comment: Try this question: [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line) - you should also be able to install it by opening it in Software Center (just click on it in File Manager). If you get any errors installing it, add these errors to your question.

Comment: so you are asking how to install it yup?

Comment: If it is installed, you can change the theme in Appearance settings or with [Unity Tweak Tool](http://askubuntu.com/a/460161/178596).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Human theme is available in the repos. You don't need to manually install the package file. Just do:

```
sudo apt-get install human-theme
```

If you want the human icon theme as well, do:

```
sudo apt-get install human-icon-theme
```

Side note:
If you double click on the package file, it should open in Software Centre, from where you can install it without using the command line.

Comment: And how to apply it ?

Comment: As @Wilf commented, use the Appearance settings. Right click on your desktop and click on 'Change Background'. Below the background selection, there's a section for themes. For more advanced settings, install Unity Tweak Tool.

Comment: While trying to install by sudo apt-get install human*theme error is E: Unable to locate package human-theme

Comment: @user73898 that is very strange, since `human-theme` is in `main` and should always be available. What does `apt-cache search human-theme ` show?